# Double action in toggleClass

Tags: jquery

Some strange behavior in my JQuery code. I want to toggle class in my tag :(

Here HTML:

```
<fieldset>
<p>
<label class="" for="mse2_resource|parent_0">
<input id="mse2_resource|parent_0" class="" type="checkbox" checked="" value="56" name="resource|parent">
<span>✔</span>
Text 1
</label>
</p>
</fieldset>
```

And JQuery:

```
$('fieldset p').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  console.log(this);
});
```

I don`t understand why script doing this at one time:

```
<p class="active">
<p class="">
```

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwLecugv/)

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: @PankajKathiriya why it is doing 2 click events at the same time

Comment: It looks like it's because of the `<label>`. Removing that fixes the problem. I guess clicking on the label produces a click event on the checkbox, and both of them propagate to the `<p>`.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `for` attribute if you wrap the label around the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expand the logged objects in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwLecugv/1/) and check for differences, you'll see that basically the only difference is that the `event.target` element is different.

This tells me that the click event is not only triggered for the `<label>` element, but also for the `<input>`. This is because all click events are redirected to the input it's targeted to.

The way to fix this is to simply check if the target is a `<label>` element. If it is, the event handler shouldn't continue, since we know the event will then be triggered for the `<input>` right away anyway. This can be done with the following bit of code at the start of the event handler:

```
if ($(e.target).is('label'))
    return;
```

But, I'd recommend putting the event handler on the input itself. Also, I'd suggest using the `change` event handler instead:

```js
$('fieldset input').change(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('p').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
/* Make .active visible in this demo */
.active {
    color: #C77;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
    <p>
        <label class="" for="mse2_resource|parent_0">
            <input id="mse2_resource|parent_0" class="" type="checkbox" checked="" value="56" name="resource|parent">
<span>✔</span>
Text 1</label>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You don't have jQuery loaded in your snippet.

Comment: Couldn't you achieve the same thing by just putting the handler on the checkbox?

Comment: @user2896218 Please see my updated answer. This version is probably better.

Comment: In my way this version don`t work :( but the first version work great.

Comment: @user2896218 I'm sorry, I forgot something in that code. This updated version does work though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore.js utilities or implement a native function for implement a debounce function.

```
var toggleAccordion = debounce(function (e) {
jQuery(this)
    .toggleClass("active")
    .parent()
    .siblings()
    .children()
    .removeClass("active");

// collapse where clicking
jQuery(this).next(".collapse").collapse("toggle");

}, 250);

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
var timeout;
return function () {
    var context = this,
        args = arguments;
    var later = function () {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
};

//Call function and pass function accordion


jQuery(carouselActive).click(toggleAccordion);
```